# Make "Done" button work on TextField Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface

When adding a textfield, the keyboard opens correctly, however I cannot get the done button to work properly. I know thee are other similar posts, however for whatever reason they do not seem to work for me.

When I say "not work" i mean the keyboard does not close.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you have the UITextFieldDelegate set in your header and that the text field is connected to the proper outlet. If not, no way for you to intercept the done button presses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this and let me know:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)aTextField
{
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Remember to add the viewController  as delegate of your text field

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for. Its a UITextFieldDelegate callback thats called anytime the Done/Return button is used on the keyboard.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

You'll need the delegate in your interface

```
@interface Class : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

If you're textfield is in a ModalViewController using the FormSheet style you need this as well.

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}
```